# How to resolve Kafka Consumer poll timeout error

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, vagrant, kafka-consumer-api

I am trying to use Apache Kafka through a vagrant machine to run a simple Kafka Consumer program.  The program get's stuck before the for loop when it tries to call the .poll(100) method.

Lot's of digging into deeper classes for debugging but not much has been found.

```
val TOPIC="testTopic"

val  props = new Properties()
props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "192.168.56.10:9092")
props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest")
props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, UUID.randomUUID().toString());

props.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer")
props.put("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer")

val consumer = new KafkaConsumer[String, String](props)

consumer.subscribe(util.Collections.singletonList(TOPIC))

while(true) {
  println("Test")
  val records = consumer.poll(100)
  for (record <- records.asScala) {
    println(record)
  }
  println("Test2")
}
```

}

Currently outputs Test and then get's stuck with no error message.  It's expected that it will output the contents of the Kafka topic.

Comment: Can you try to use something like `consumer.poll(new Duration(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS))` instead of `consumer.poll(100)`?

Comment: @AlekseyIsachenkov you are right, but I will just add that to do that it requires changing the Kafka client version.

Answer (score 1):

You need to **upgrade** your **kafka-clients version to 2.0.0 or above**. When the kafka server is down, for example, using the poll method from `KafkaConsumer` class you will get **stuck in the internal loop waiting for the broker to become available again.**

According to [KIP-266](https://kafka.apache.org/20/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html):

> ConsumerRecords
>
> poll​(long timeout)
>
> Deprecated.  Since 2.0. **Use poll(Duration)**, which does not block
>   beyond the timeout awaiting partition assignment. See KIP-266 for more
>   information.

In your case:

```scala
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer; 
import scala.concurrent.duration._

// ...
val timeout = Duration(100, MILLISECONDS) 

while(true) {
  println("Test")
  val records = consumer.poll(timeout)
  for (record <- records.asScala) {
    println(record)
  }
  println("Test2")
}

//...
```

In conclusion, you just need to import the new version of the `KafkaConsumer` class and pass the timeout parameter to the new poll method as an instance of the `Duration` object.